# Serving resources from `node_modules` dir

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen, compojure

I want to serve files from `node_modules` directory in project root.

so for example I added to my page this:

```
[:link {:href "/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" :rel "stylesheet" :type "text/css"}]
```

now I need to tell compojure to serve statically anything that's in `node_modules` directory, and I can't find a way.

It works if I move node_modules to `resources/public` dir, but I don't want that. I need to find a way to serve files from anywhere in the project directory (in this case from `./node_modules`)

I tried adding `:resource-paths ["node_modules"]` to `profiles.clj`,

I tried `(compojure.route/resources "node_modules" {:root "../.." })`,
that still didn't work.

Comment: You may symlink node_modules to the resources directory

Comment: @OlegTheCat that's not a solution, that's hiding the problem. Almost equal to moving the folder in there

Comment: I think you may have forgotten the leading `/` in the first argument to resources.
Also have you tried running `lein classpath` at the root of the project? If `node_modules` is not in there, `resources` won't work as it only serves files from the classpath; in that case you are probably better off using `route/files` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did:

added `:resource-paths ["node_modules"]` to project.clj - [take a look at leiningen's sample](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj)

and then `(compojure.route/resources "/" {:root "" })`. Seems it worked.

**upd**: this apparently exposed things that should not be exposed. e.g. it's possible now to download `project.clj` by navigating to it in the browser. not good.

**upd 2**: `(compojure.route/files "/" {:root "node_modules" })` this time it's right.

Answer (score -1):

Symlink the file(s) or use `@import` in something in your static files to include your font-awesome css. I haven't tried this but you might also either create a project_root/special_css folder and add it to the `css-dirs` in project.clj or try adding the special file itself to the vector (not sure if that would work).

Comment: That's not a solution I'm looking for, the fact that the given example about .css - mere coincidence. I need a way to serve static resources from anywhere, not just `resources/public`. Symlinking not the right way either and I hope you too, feel that way - it creates other problems, including of deployment type.

Comment: Serving public resources from anywhere causes problems moreso than symlinking to a dedicated public folder does. What is the motivation for serving arbitrary public files from non-public directories?

Comment: not "arbitrary", but stuff that's in `node_modules` folder. It's fairly safe. It is possible to move it to `resources/public`, but I want to keep `node_modules` intact.

Comment: `npm` uses `node_modules` that's default directory for the packages, it's possible to tell it to keep it somewhere else using `.npmrc` file, but as I said - I'd like to keep the folder in its default location